# OutofMemoryError Crashing the application

Tags: android, android-layout

i am implementing the `listview` with image and `framelayout` (Containing `Linearlayout` and button), when i scroll the `listview` many times from top to bottom then after some time application gets crashed giving the error:

> outofMemoryError.

Comment: Most likely you are not freeing up the images or loading too many images. Post the Logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

As Great Answer Given By Fedor you should Do Something Like Below to Resolve your issue.

To fix **OutOfMemory** you should do something like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

This inSampleSize option reduces memory consumption.

Here's a complete method. First it reads image size without decoding the content itself. Then it finds the best inSampleSize value, it should be a power of 2. And finally the image is decoded.

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

you can refere [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) for More Description. Hope it will help you.